My Hydraulic brakes are seizing up and I have tried everything. Help
So I have a mountain bike and the rear brakes seize up when I squeeze the lever. I have identified the problem as the pistons being too far out. I have tried to push the pistons back in but they wouldn’t budge so I opened the little screw on the brake price and it released some fluid and the pistons stuck. Oh joy. But then when I squeezed the lever again the brakes seized again. I tried this several times but the only thing I got was reduced pressure in the pipes which obviously was due to the multiple times I opened the screw on the brake. So I tried looking to see if there is any gunk on the pistons that would prevent them from moving properly and they looked pretty clean. I also tried pushing the pistons out a bit and lubricating them with some of the DOT for the bike but that didn’t have any effect. So my question is what else could be done to fix it?

Are your brake pads or rotors worn down? Is the brake pad spring in place and intact? I’ve read that sometimes for stuck pistons you have to move them in and out several times. Since you’ve lost some hydraulic fluid I’d do a full bleed (with a bleed block in place which pushes the pistons all the way in).

Welcome to the site.   Can you share the brand and model of your brakes?      Clearly, don't ride the bike till the brakes are fixed and working reliably.

I had stuck pistons on my gravel bike recently (105).  They seemed to be fixed now.  What I did was:

Take the wheel and pads off.
Put a tool between the pistons, but not a bleed block (a tyre lever would be good, I used a fat screwdriver)
Squeeze the lever repeatedly to push the pistons out a little further than in normal use, holding them back with the screwdriver.
See which one stuck
Clean everything
Apply brake fluid (mineral oil as mine are Shimano) around the pistons, just a drop or 2 on each
Exercise them a few times with the brake lever and screwdriver, being sure to push them right in.  This took gentle levering against the other piston, changing the position/angle of the screwdriver.
Wipe them down again, round the outside
Apply another drop of oil
Exercise/test them again, and they returned by themselves.

Note that the spring holds the pads against the pistons, but isn't strong enough to push the pistons in.  A failed spring (which I've had a few of on my MTB) causes only very light rubbing, even if the spring itself contacts the rotor.
Also note that at no point was much force required, but sometimes a little jiggling, and a plastic tool would be a better idea than the metal one I went for.

I has something similar happen with an Avid brake. I suspect the return valve in the lever was blocked/jammed in a way fluid could go into the brake line to apply the brakes but could not return into the lever when the brakes were released. This caused the brakes to come on and not release. Bleeding fluid fixed it till you applied the brakes.
Permanent fix was easy in my case. I replaced the brakes with new Shimano's.
In your case it might be worth overhauling the lever.

Good point - a partial diagnostic test to tell whether your approach or mine is required is that if one piston retracts, the other is probably sticky, but if neither retracts (possibly after a little fiddling) it could be the return valve

Thanks for all the help guys! what would I do if it was a return valve issue? That seems to fit my problem.
